# Running flask script from parent directory

Tags: python, flask

I have python script `python_proj.py`. There're few prints and simple functions. It calls a flask script:

```
os.system("flask run")
```

Flask script is in the same directory. Everything works when I run these from terminal in current directory:

```
user123@user123:~/PycharmProjects/python_and_bash$ ./python_proj.py
```

But when I'm in parent directory (for example `'~'`) and I try to run this script:

```
user123@user123:~$ ./PycharmProjects/python_and_bash/python_proj.py
```

It doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

How to do it? I need to send this app for non-technical mates. It should work everywhere and everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines in my proj_python.py script. Now it works.

```
 path = pathlib.Path(os.path.realpath(__file__))
 path = str(path.parent) + "/app.py"
 os.system(path)
```

Be aware! Don't put `os.system("flask run")` after these lines! It will cause that flask script will start 2 times! First start will be caused by: `os.system(path)`, after `ctrl+c` or interrupt signal `os.system("flask run")` will start second time.

Answer (score 2):

You could find the absolute path of the directory of your script using this code:

```
import pathlib


parent_folder = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute() # Get the absolute path of parent folder

os.environ['FLASK_APP'] = parent_folder / 'your_flask_app.py' # Set environment variable
os.system("flask run")
```

Comment: Does your solution work in e.g parent of parent directory, or parent of parent of parent dir? Does we can still run it in current directory?
I tihnk author doesn't know  this/is/your/path/app.py on other machines. Solution has to be more general I think

Comment: Yup, as a 'patrykoz' said. Solution has to be general. I don't know paths on machines :(

Comment: Okay,lets suppose I can get paths. Where to  write it? In flask script or in proj_python.py script?

Comment: the `parent_folder` variable gets the path of the parent folder so the `this/is/your/path/app.py` is can be replaced by the **parent_folder** variable. Sorry I wasn't clear about this in my answer.